How do I pass my parameters as a string array (as args) in JSR223 Assertion?
I  am trying to pass the following 3 parameters in JSR223 Assertion as a string array containing the parameter split on whitespace.

${__samplerName()}
a description string called ID
vars.get("Value_of_ID")

How I can define the parameters in the JSR223 Assertion section and acccess them in the separate groovy script later?
I defined/passed one argument/parameter as '${__samplerName()}' in the parameters section of JSR223 Assertion and managed to successfully access it in the groovy script.
def call_name = Parameters ? args[0] : "NONE" .

I am not sure how to pass two more parameters (along with the above) as an array.

Exactly the same manner, args[1], args[2] etc.
args is itself an array of Strings so you can just use it if needed:

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?

Thanks, Ivan. I  figured it out a few days back
